# Multiple element, same class, get value of one element - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this multiple elements with the same class.

```
<div class="test-container">
    <a class="dup-class">
        Get Value
    </a>

    <div class="product-list-col">
        1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test-container">
    <a class="dup-class">
        Get Value
    </a>

    <div class="product-list-col">
        2
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test-container">
    <a class="dup-class">
        Get Value
    </a>

    <div class="product-list-col">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

If I click the the `<a>` tag on the first div, it should alert the value of `.product-list-col` value which is `1`

if I click the second div of anchor tag, it should alert `2`

here's the code for it

```
$(".dup-class").on('click', function() {
    cont = $(this + " .product-list-col").text();
    alert(cont);
});
```

Any solution for this stuff?

Here's the jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/Vigiliance/PLeDs/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use siblings(), the reason why your code doesn't work is because it's selecting all `.product-list-col`

```
$(".dup-class").on('click', function () {
    cont = $(this).siblings('.product-list-col').text();
    alert(cont);
});
```

or use .next()

```
$(".dup-class").on('click', function () {
    cont = $(this).next('.product-list-col').text();
    alert(cont);
});
```

Comment: I'd say that `siblings` is a much better option because `next` would be bound to the current DOM formations...

Comment: You can also do this by having jQuery search for the element within the parent(), by proving context to the jQuery search as a second parameter: $('.product-list-col',$(this).parent()).text(); in case the element stops being the sibling.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
$(".dup-class").on('click', function() {
    cont = $(this).next().text(); // this is the line where change done
    alert(cont);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PLeDs/2/

Comment: This technically works, but is a bad idea as it will break as soon as the DOM structure changes.

Comment: This solution was for a specific kind of problem. If you are sure that next element will be this only, you do this, otherwise we have options like `siblings('.someclass')`

Comment: I was just pointing out that it would be bad practice to rely on DOM structure being fixed and never changing.