# Getting specific id or class when there are multiple elements with the same id or class from the DOM

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery

I have a rating system made as dropdown menu. Now I have multiple elements with the same id (which is book_id) and I'm trying to get this id only from the book that the user want to rate. The problem now whatever the book that the user rates always getting back the id of the first book in my web app. I have read here [How can I apply a jQuery function to all elements with the same ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274982/how-can-i-apply-a-jquery-function-to-all-elements-with-the-same-id) about how to solve this problem, but still it didn't work with me.

So, when I click on the dropdown menu in a specific book and choose any number(I.e "2")
I want when I got redirect to the other route know what is the rate and which book did the user rate. I also read this but didn't solve my problem [Multiple element, same class, get value of one element - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377491/multiple-element-same-class-get-value-of-one-element-jquery)

```
    <div class="row g-3">
      <!--render the books in within cards-->
      {% for book in books %}
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">

            <div style="background-color:#6e6b64" class="card">
               {% if book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail %}

                 <img src="{{book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail}}">
               {% endif %}

               <div  class="card-body">
               <h5 style="color:red" class="card-title">{{book.volumeInfo.title}}</h5>
               <p style="color:blue" class="card-text">{{book.volumeInfo.authors}}</p>
               <form style="margin-bottom:5px" action="/addcomment" method="get">
                  <input name="book" type ="hidden" class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="book_id" name="book_id" value="{{book.id}}" type="text">
                  <a href="{{book.volumeInfo.infoLink}}" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">add comment</button>
              </form>
                 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bar-rating/1.2.2/themes/fontawesome-stars-o.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                  <!--get the user rate-->
                 <label class="custom-select">
                  Give your rate
                  <select class="custom-select" style="width:200px;" id="example">
                   <option  value="">rate</option>
                   <option value="1">1</option>
                   <option  value="2">2</option>
                   <option value="3">3</option>
                   <option value="4">4</option>
                   <option value="5">5</option>
                 </select>
                </label>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
                </script>
                <script>

                 jQuery(function(){
                  jQuery("[id=example]").on('change', function () {
                     var book_name =document.querySelector("[id=book_id]").value;
                     console.log(book_name);
                     var rating  = $(this).val(); // get selected value
                     if (rating ) {
                         window.location = "/rate/"+book_name +"/"+rating;

                               }
                     return false;

                               });
                            });
               </script>

                </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           {% endfor %}
       </div>
   </div>
```

And here is the python code

```
@app.route("/rate/<book_name>/<rates>")
@login_required
 def rate(book_name,rates):
 all_rates = db.execute("SELECT SUM(rate) AS w FROM rating WHERE book_id=?",book_name)
 print(all_rates)
 print(rates)
 print(book_name)
 if all_rates[0]["w"]:
  number = int(all_rates[0]["w"])+ 1/len(all_rates[0])+ 1
  db.execute("INSERT INTO rating (user_id, rate,book_id) VALUES(?, ?,?)",session["user_id"], number,book_name)
  print(all_rates[0]["w"])
 else:
    db.execute("INSERT INTO rating (user_id, rate,book_id) VALUES(?, ?,?)",session["user_id"], rates,book_name)

 return apology("todo")
```

Comment: So you just want to select the current ID?

Comment: Yes, exactly where the user clicks

Comment: Are these options are going to be your book IDs i.e.,. id="example" ?

Comment: My book IDs are in the input tag. These options are just for the rating system

Comment: Every-time there will be one id of the book, so you are having issue in getting it in the jQuery part?

Comment: Yeah, when I try to get the book_id of the book which the user clicked to give it his rate I always getting back the id of the first book doesn't matter which book the user tried to rate

Comment: The issue is with the code ( server side ) not JS. You need to fix how you are calling the book id. Do you have a live link for it?

Comment: I don't.  But I can edit my question and add the code for the rate route